# set the same height columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have image gallery with 4 images.

Images can be different height, but i need with html/css make the same height columns (images stretched).

Everything works fine, until I do not put `<!DOCTYPE html>`

All other page works with this DOCTYPE, so i can't remove it.

How fix my code, that it functions well with my DOCTYPE?

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.cb {
  clear: both;
}
.fl {
  float: left;
}
.fr {
  float: right;
}
.col1 {
  width: 40%;
  flex-flow: column;
  display: flex;
}
.col2 {
  width: 60%;
}
.gallery-top {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-top">
  <div class="fl col1">
    <div class="">
      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=15&txt=150%C3%9780&w=150&h=40" />
    </div>
    <div class="" style="flex: 1; display: flex;">
      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=15&txt=150%C3%9780&w=150&h=120" />
    </div>
    <div class="cb"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="fl col2">
    <div class="">
      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=15&txt=150%C3%9780&w=150&h=80" />
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=15&txt=150%C3%9780&w=150&h=80" />
    </div>
    <div class="cb"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cb"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you update the snippet with a good repro information?

Comment: If you're using `<!DOCTYPE html>`, you're using html5. In html5 you don't need to close self-closing tags like `<img>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<!DOCTYPE html>` tells the browser that the code present is HTML5, therefore the browser understands it correctly. All of your documents should have it in place.

Please see this **[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_declaration)** for further reading.

Your markup(html) is a bit messy, You have empty class attributes. Try to **always** keep Your code clean and organized. Use classes, id's and reference them in Your stylesheet properly. **Do not** use inline styles unless Your specific issue at hand requires them.

This said, I suggest that You learn more about using flexbox and avoid using it inline for future instances.

You can find more about using flex-box **[here.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**

> *I made a* **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qe20e5ve/)** *to help you better understand the concept.*

Comment: Thanks for code, but this code works only if images is the same height.
If in the same column one image is 40 and second 120 - then you get white space in bottom.

Comment: This might be it https://jsfiddle.net/qe20e5ve/1/ , but the columns will have to be with a fixed equal width, otherwise you will experience the gaps again. What you are after is not possible with Flexbox, and you will have to use a plugin like http://masonry.desandro.com/